# google login using cordova googleplus plugin

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

I want login using google account in cordova app for android platform by using **cordova  googleplus plugin**. So I have made an android app on console developers google on google account and integrate it with my cordova app but when I tried to run my cordova app on emulator I am facing error with `code:8` and when I run on android phone the error becomes `error:12501`.

So how to resolve it to run google login on my cordova app?

Comment: Is google play service installed in emulator ?

Answer (score 0):

Add your package name to the config.xml file as below :

Here is how to specify the Device API for Android projects :

```
<feature name="Device">
<param name="android-package" value="com.xxxx.xxxxx" />
</feature>
```

Here's how the element appears for iOS projects :

```
<feature name="Device">
<param name="ios-package" value="com.xxxx.xxxxx" />
<param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
```